# Redirect Whole website to new domain with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Can Anyone help me to find the solution how to redirect my whole old url to new url.

For example

My old ulr is:

[www.example.com.au/blog](http://www.example.com.au/blog)

I want to redirect this domain to new domain like that

[www.newdomain.com.au/blog](http://www.newdomain.com.au/blog)

Comment: “Redirect whole website” - but the example you gave is just a single URL? Does the old and new domains point to different servers or the same server/filesystem? Have you tired _anything_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Redirect 301 / www.newdomain.com.au/blog
```

More infos [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Comment: Now I add the redirect sucessfully but now old domain pdf not redirect to the new domain pdf for example:

Here is the old url: https://www.example.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/2022-Smidge-Retail-Price-List.pdf

Here is the new url: https://www.newurl.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/2022-Smidge-Retail-Price-List.pdf

Comment: I want to redirect all the pdf's to new domain

Comment: Try checking if the correct url is set in file `wp-config.php`. It might be that in that file you still have the old url set so all the `wp-content/uploads` refer to the old url